# What Calculus book do you suggest for someone going into the Sciences/Medical Fields?

Tags: calculus, reference-request

I know there are other threads about Calculus textbooks but none that I saw specifically geared towards someone wanting to self teach themselves a bit of Calculus before entering into the Sciences.

Anyone know of something? Is there any Math For Premed books out there? (I'm actually just starting Prereqs to go towards Doctor of Physical Therapy)

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need calculus for medical fields. Trust me I'm living with two medics in there last year and they haven't done any calculus and in the UK everyone is trained to the same standard. I would think there would be even less need for Maths if you went into Physical therapy side. I suppose you might need some stats, however they will probably teach you it and it would be very specific.

Comment: Calc is not required, Statistics is. But understanding Calc will help do the Physics coursework and really even the Chemistry courses. I know I don't need high level calculus which is why I'm asking for a good alternative to the Calculus books that are typically geared towards mathematicians, businessmen and engineers

Answer (score 1):

Gilbert Strang's *Calculus*-the first edition is available online for free download at MIT OpenCourseWare. Like all Strang's marvelous textbooks, it's applied mathematics with a brain. It explains rather then proves (although it does that too,of course) and it has dozens of wonderful applications to physics, chemistry,economics and of special interest for you,biology. And all of it is done with hundreds of beautiful, detailed diagrams and graphs. It's a book all intelligent people can and should read.

Comment: Seems I can't vote up since I don't have reputation on this part of StackExchange/Overflow but Thanks Mathemagician! Going to check it out right now.